# Schicke das zu mir! und/oder Schicke mir das zu!

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, verb-usage, separable-verb

Für das Verb zuschicken ist angeblich die richtige Satzordnung

> Schicke das mir zu!

Ich wunderte mich aber ob

> Schicke das zu mir!

auch eine richtige Reihenfolge ist. Ist die Bedeutung nun gleich oder sollte man zu immer am Ende haben?

Answer (score 3):

Im zweiten Fall kommt das Verb *zuschicken* gar nicht vor, sondern ein normales *schicken*. Ein wesentlicher Unterschied in der Bedeutung beider Beispiele ist, dass *zuschicken* den Postweg oder vielleicht gerade noch e-Mail abdeckt, in der zweiten Formulierung auch Personen gemeint sein können. Einen Kunden, der eine Frage hat, die man selbst nicht beantworten kann, kann man z. B. *zu* einer Kollegin *schicken*.

Answer (score 2):

> Schicke das mir zu!

Das ist das Verb *zuschicken* mit einem Dativobjekt *mir*.

> Schicke das zu mir!

Das ist das Verb *schicken* mit einem Adverbial *zu mir*.

Der Unterschied besteht darin, dass ein Dativobjekt angibt, wer von der Handlung profitiert (oder allgemein: wer die Konsequenzen zu tragen hat) während ein Adverbial mit der Präposition *zu* eine Richtung angibt.

Man kann auch beides kombinieren, allerdings erwartet man das Verb *zuschicken* normalerweise nicht mit einer Richtungsangabe.

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> Spiel deinem Mitspieler den Ball möglichst zum Tor hin zu.

(Also: Spiel keinen Rückpass, wenn es geht, sondern einen Vorwärtspass. Und dabei immer schön auf die Abseitsregel achten.)

Das ist das Verb *zuspielen* und *deinem Mitspieler* ist das Dativobjekt. Der profitiert von deinem Pass. Und zusätzlich gibt es noch eine Richtungsangabe *zum Tor hin*.